# Error al verificar si un registro existe en la base de datos

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

El siguiente código me da el error:

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in...
Lo que hace es verificar si un usuario existe en la base de datos.

```
$cate = $_POST['cat'];
$veri = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name = '$cate' ";
$result = $db->select($veri); 
$numRowsNew = $result->num_rows;
```

```
if($numRowsNew >= 1) {
    echo "El nombre de usuario ya existe.";
} else {
    echo "Disponible.";
}
```

Comment: y tu tabla de usuario se llama `category`? en fin... el error lo esta reportando por que estas tratando de obtener una propiedad de algo que no es un objeto, como no dice nada mas el error no tengo claridad si el error esta en `$db->select` o en `$db->num_rows`

Comment: Estas usando algun framework no?

Answer (score 3):

Al momento de construir el string de tu consulta debes concadenar la variable para que la imprima dentro del mismo string:

$cate = $_POST['cat'];
$veri = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name = '" .$cate. "' ";

Ahora, si usarás MySQLI por objetos debes hacer:

$result = $db->query($veri);

Igual puedes usar la forma prepare para concadenar variables en tu consuta:

// debes preparar la consulta sustituyendo donde irá la variable por un ?...
$prepare = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM category WHERE name=?');
//ahora vuelcas las variables usando bind_param donde debes indicar primero el tipo de variable que esperas y luego la variable...
$prepare->bind_param('s', $cate);
// ejecutar la consulta...
$prepare->execute();

Con esto puedes usar facilmente variables dentro de las consultas con la ventaja de que al hacerlo con el prepare automáticamente se aplica un mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tu fallo está en que no es `select`, es `query`.

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
$cate = $_POST['cat'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name = '$cate'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {
    echo "El nombre de usuario ya existe.";
} else {
    echo "Disponible.";
}
```